# Wifi driver installation without wifi

Tags: firmware, wifi-driver, parrot-os

I recently changed to a new laptop and did a dual boot of windows and parrot security-4.7(as per my prev laptop). However, I found out that the installer could not detect my WiFi driver and I had to install a non free firmware for my WiFi driver Ax201. I tried loading these non-free firmware during installation but it could not be detected, so I decided to install these firmware only later on. I downloaded a deb file from Windows (as i have no WiFi) and installed it successfully. However, network manager still could not detect my wifi driver and when I ran the dmesg command:

```
[    9.408029] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    9.408135] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    9.408140] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 142708358
[    9.408142] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.13675109.0
[    9.408144] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5CC40893 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    9.408146] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCBB1FC53 | trm_hw_status0
[    9.408148] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9DD7B9BD | trm_hw_status1
[    9.408149] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x04E1BA02 | branchlink2
[    9.408151] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x003DA345 | interruptlink1
[    9.408153] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA1E65E7E | interruptlink2
[    9.408154] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF7D8F7FA | data1
[    9.408156] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x15129B61 | data2
[    9.408157] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0106C00 | data3
[    9.408159] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFF847F2 | beacon time
[    9.408160] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5BB7C737 | tsf low
[    9.408162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9DC73041 | tsf hi
[    9.408163] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x012078E9 | time gp1
[    9.408165] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE5F2EA3D | time gp2
[    9.408166] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD37EEFDD | uCode revision type
[    9.408168] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x627A8A59 | uCode version major
[    9.408169] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0094D010 | uCode version minor
[    9.408171] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFFFD21C | hw version
[    9.408172] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFDC5DFEF | board version
[    9.408174] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBDDA47DF | hcmd
[    9.408175] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01231446 | isr0
[    9.408177] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x832037BC | isr1
[    9.408178] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFDAE35FB | isr2
[    9.408180] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEBED3E86 | isr3
[    9.408182] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA0986412 | isr4
[    9.408183] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x641EB277 | last cmd Id
[    9.408185] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x15517E3D | wait_event
[    9.408186] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5EBFE997 | l2p_control
[    9.408188] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x102A2C8E | l2p_duration
[    9.408189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4AC0B881 | l2p_mhvalid
[    9.408191] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD7FE1732 | l2p_addr_match
[    9.408192] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEB0AFF9C | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    9.408194] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x760557A1 | timestamp
[    9.408195] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x418B4B19 | flow_handler
[    9.408242] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    9.408243] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    9.408245] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    9.408247] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    9.408248] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008D49C | umac branchlink2
[    9.408250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[    9.408252] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    9.408253] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[    9.408255] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | umac data2
[    9.408256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | umac data3
[    9.408258] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
[    9.408259] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x13675109 | umac minor
[    9.408261] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00006065 | frame pointer
[    9.408263] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer
[    9.408264] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    9.408266] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    9.408288] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    9.408308] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    9.408311] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    9.408331] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00070043 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    9.408335] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A481 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    9.408355] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    9.408358] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    9.408378] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    9.408381] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    9.408401] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    9.408407] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    9.408429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    9.408451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    9.408489] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5fd8, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    9.408491] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    9.408494] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    9.421944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Full result in the link (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ITJByxDcnt_1hxft0GtBx7dkVcl37Ew0LxO8xunZtJ0/edit?usp=drivesdk) which I could not comprehend despite Googling. Any help would be greatly appreciated (i enjoy using parrot alot). Thanks in advance for your time and patience O:-)

Comment: The AX cards are pretty new so support is still a bit shaky. It might be simpler to grab a cheap USB wifi adaptor or ethernet to get it set up first You probably need firmware-iwlwifi from a non free repo. You *might* be able to sneak by with grabbing packages from the equivilent debian repo - though I don't know which debian release corresponds to parrot. https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-iwlwifi seems to support AX200 however

Comment: I got my installation package from the non free buster release since parrot is debian 10, and it got me the error message up there. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You may need a newer one. Got backports?

Comment: I am not really sure where I can get one. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/firmware-iwlwifi Its a repository - basically get the packages for wifi related stuff from there.

Comment: Hmmm I tried this but it did not work, but I already bought myself an external WiFi adapter which works perfectly with Parrot 4.7 One last question: would they include the necessary firmware for my inbuilt WiFi adapter in future releases of parrot?

Comment: Probably. It works out of the box on Ubuntu 19.10… also a Debian derivative

Comment: Ok thank you. Do I need to close this question?

Comment: I'd leave it open. Others may have similar issues for a while

Comment: Ok thks for your help:-D